# Access subnet from other subnet

Tags: networking, routing, nat, tp-link

We're running a FritzBox from our DSL-Provider in front of our TP-Link router. Now we want to use the DHCP-Server of the TP-Link, so all clients get a IP of the range 192.168.0.0/16. But we also want to access the 192.168.0.0/16 network from our FritzBox 10.0.0.0/24 network, so all clients in this network can access the clients in the TP-Link network, without port forwarding or anything else.

What is the best way to achieve this?
I already tried a static route in the FritzBox, but it isn't possible to access the clients behind the TP-Link:

```
Network: 192.168.0.0
Netmask: 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 10.0.0.2 (The TP-Link IP in the Fritzbox network)
```

Here's a diagram of the network structure: [Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGbKA.png)

Comment: Your consumer-grade TP-Link router isn't up to the task. It doesn't know how to do anything else other than NAT things out of its WAN interface.

Comment: But it's possible to disable NAT on the WAN interface.

Comment: The model number is written in the diagram. Just disabled NAT on the TP-Link, but then you can't access the FritzBox network from the TP-Link network anymore, so you have no internet access.